# Bulid SQLite-Net Extensions in visual studio professional 2013 but not successful

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-store-apps, windows-store, sqlite-net-extensions

I am new to windows app and I am going to build the sqlite-net extension project to .dll file in order to make the models have the relationship attribute of one-to-many, one-to-one, many-to-many.

Link: https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions

This is the info that it shows when I open the project in visual studio 2013.

> Unsupported
>
> This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the
>   following projects. The project types may not be installed or this
>   version of Visual Studio may not support them.  For more information
>   on enabling these project types or otherwise migrating your assets,
>   please see the details in the "Migration Report" displayed after
>   clicking OK.
>      - IntegrationTests.Touch-MvvmCross, "C:\Users\**\Downloads\sqlite-net-extensions\sqlite-net-extensions\IntegrationTests.Touch\IntegrationTests.Touch-MvvmCross.csproj"
>      - IntegrationTests.Touch-PCL, "C:\Users\**\Downloads\sqlite-net-extensions\sqlite-net-extensions\IntegrationTests.Touch\IntegrationTests.Touch-PCL.csproj"
>
> No changes required These projects can be opened in Visual Studio
>   2013, Visual Studio 2012, and Visual Studio 2010 SP1 without changing
>   them.
>      - Tests, "C:\Users\**\Downloads\sqlite-net-extensions\sqlite-net-extensions\Tests\Tests.csproj"
>      - MvvmCross, "MvvmCross"
>      - SQLiteNetExtensions-MvvmCross, "C:\Users\**\Downloads\sqlite-net-extensions\sqlite-net-extensions\SQLiteNetExtensions\SQLiteNetExtensions-MvvmCross.csproj"
>      - SQLiteNetExtensions-PCL, "C:\Users\**\Downloads\sqlite-net-extensions\sqlite-net-extensions\SQLiteNetExtensions\SQLiteNetExtensions-PCL.csproj"
>      - SQLiteNetExtensions, "C:\Users\**\Downloads\sqlite-net-extensions\sqlite-net-extensions\SQLiteNetExtensions.sln"

I try to build it and it shows some errors. So I right click the project and download the missing packages. When I try to build it again, it shows these errors:
[image]

Does anyone successfully bulid it to .dll file or anyone can fix the problems like these?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Did you explicit set build platform to x64, x86 or ARM? "Any cpu" is not valid configuration. Also don't forget to add reference to `Microsoft Visual c++ Runtime package`

Comment: @Veikedo Thanks for your advises, I created it and made it work already~thx:)

Answer (score 1):

The Integration test projects are MonoTouch projects, that won't open in Visual Studio unless you have [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com) Business license installed in your PC.

However, the SQLite-Net Extensions project is a standard PCL project and you will be able to compile it from Visual Studio without Xamarin. The problem that you are describing is probably related to not having the SQLite-Net dependency downloaded.

Make sure that you have [NuGet Package Manager](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c) plugin installed and [restore NuGet packages](https://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore) for the project to restore the dependencies and it should work.

You can also download the pre-compiled DLL from the [Download page](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/downloads) in the project page.

Comment: I got the SQLite-Net downloaded, I solved it with changing the build platform, anyway~ thx mate:)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with changing the build platform. Thx guys!